# how to use json_decode on a large file

Tags: php, file, json

I have 170mb JSON file (yes, the whole DB)... its third party and its all I got to work with.

I've set the ini to 850m, but still get memory error.

How can I read the json file record by record OR in small chunks, as to not get memory error?

What ever I try, when I run the json_decode function, its trying to do the WHOLE file?

Either what I've tried is done wrong, I'm missing something, OR it can't be done?

any alternative to json_decode function?

Or some way to only read 1 record at a time?

Comment: Search for a streaming json parser.  For example, [this one](http://www.salsify.com/blog/json-streaming-parser-for-php).

Comment: thanks, but I have an issue/question using that one? I have this code: 

$recordList = $listener->get_json();
for ($rec_counter = 0; $rec_counter< count($recordList); ++$rec_counter) {
        $record = $recordList[$rec_counter];
        echo $record["name"]."<br>";
}

and it works with the sample json file it gave. I've tried it on the 170meg file and its taking forever, plus I need to set the execution time to a large time?

my question, is that streaming parser STILL loading up the whole file BEFORE its starts to process it?

Comment: If it's written correctly, and you use it correctly, it won't load it all at once.  I just know the concept, I've never used one.  Search for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this quite useful plugin,
I used it and it helped me a lot!

https://github.com/kuma-giyomu/JSONParser

Comment: thanks, I tried that parser but it gave errors:

Warning: stream_get_meta_data() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in JLexBase.php on line 74

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in JLexBase.php on line 118

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in JLexBase.php on line 118

at that point, I tried the parser mentioned by FakeRain... it was easier/shorter/simpler and worked... however, i still have a question that I posted above, about it :)

Comment: My json file contains an json_decod'ed array of objects.   [{"prop1": "valu", "prop2": "val2", "prop3": "val3", "pro4": "val4"}, {"prop1": "valu", "prop2": "val2", "prop3": "val3", "pro4": "val4"}..... ]

Parsing fails for this data. Any recommendation?